# How do I check if selected value of the ListBox is not selected in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, validation

This code will display the selected value from the listbox. E.g. if I sellect **Item 1** I will get the following output: **You have selected Item 1**.

```
Label1.Text = "You have selected " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "<br />";
```

But if I don't select anything and click on Submit button, I will get: **You have selected**

What would I need to make it display ***"You have not selected anything. Please select at least 1 item."***

*UPDATE: I am using ASP.NET WebForms.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**
The below answer is actually incorrect (left for history). Once you access the `SelectedIndex` property, when nothing is selected, the list will immediately make the first item selected, and return zero.

So pretty much the only choice that remains is to have some kind of "dummy item" very first in the list, and check for `SelectedIndex == 0`.

The above, however, is only true for `DropDownList`. Other controls derived from `ListControl` (i.e. `ListBox` or `RadioButtonList`) will correctly show `SelectedIndex == -1`.

**Here goes the incorrect answer**:
Check the `SelectedIndex` property. If nothing is selected, it will have the value of -1.

```
if ( DropDownList1.SelectedIndex < 0 )
{
    Label1.Text = "You have not selected anything";
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "You have selected " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: Oh there you go. So it has to be less than 0. I've tried with 0, and with null but it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @Sahat: This answer is actually incorrect, as I have just found by looking in Reflector. Please see my update for correct answer.

Comment: I see what you mean Fyodor, but it works here with the code that you've posted the first time. It show You have not selected anything, just as I want it to be. Perhaps it's the new feature of ASP.NET 4.0?

Comment: Well, I'm actually looking at ASP.NET 4.0 as well. Maybe you have some other kind of control, not the `DropDownList`?

Comment: I think I've confused everyone including myself by using ListBox control named DropDownList1. It is ListBox which is why it probably lets me use that code.

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull!:

> Use the SelectedIndex property to
>   programmatically specify or determine
>   the index of the selected item from
>   the DropDownList  control. **An item is
>   always selected in the DropDownList 
>   control**. You cannot clear the
>   selection from every item in the list
>   at the same time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex.aspx